# Concat multiple reactive requests to one Mono

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I noticed in the reactive libraries there are Tuples, but what do I do if there are more than 8 Tuples?

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/function/Tuples.html#fromArray-java.lang.Object:A-

Example code that seems to work, but is there a better way to use some sort of collector?

```
private Mono<List<String>> getContent(List<String> ids) {
    List<String> allContent = new ArrayList<>();
    Mono<List<String>> allContentMono = Mono.empty();
    for(String id : ids) {
        allContentMono = callApi(id)
        .flatMap(result -> result.bodyToMono(String.class))
        .map(str -> {
            allContent.add(str); 
            return allContent;
        });
    }
    return allContentMono;
}
```

Why did the tuple size stop at 8? (haven't looked around for the documentation on why, but not my main concern)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` (which uses `TupleN`) is for when you want to create values by compositon, out of a combination of sources. Eg. out of a `Flux<FirstName>` and `Flux<LastName>` you want a `Flux<FullName>`, that emits one `FullName` for each incoming `FistName`/`LastName` pair.

For your use case, where you want to execute multiple calls (possibly in parallel) and collect the results in a list, `flatMap` is enough:

```
private Mono<List<String>> getContent(List<String> ids) {
    return Flux
        .fromIterable(ids)
        .flatMap(id -> callApi(id))
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class))
        .collectList();
}
```

`Tuple` is an immutable, fixed-size data structure, used by `zip` as convenience when you don't want to create a dedicated POJO. It doesn't make sense to try and support unlimited sizes so we stopped at eight. There is a `zip` variant that will aggregate more than 8 sources, but will make you work with an `Object[]` instead of a `Tuple`.